# Do I have to make a partition to uninstall windows?

Tags: system-installation, windows-10

I want to get rid of windows 10 in my Acer aspire one and install Ubuntu 16.04 on that same drive.

Do I need to make a partition for that matter? Or just boot my USB drive and install Ubuntu over my windows 10?

Comment: No need to to create extra partition, just install over windows.

Comment: you say is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the Windows 10 partitions (recovery, system_reserved and windata), then create a swap and an ext4 partitions, then install Ubuntu to the ext partition. Ubuntu doesn't need any of the Windows partitions. You can doo all that very easy, like this: Create a LiveUSB Ubuntu in Windows, then reboot into usb mode. When the live Ubuntu starts, choose the Try option (not the Install option). Ubuntu desktop should come up momentarily. Open GParted and delete the Windows partitions (ntfs partitions). Create swap and ext4 partitions. Close GParted and click on the Install Ubuntu button.

Comment: Can't you just choose the "erase and use entire disk" option in the Ubuntu installer, instead of removing and re-creating partitions manually?

Comment: Is there a problem if I have more than 1 partition in a 32GB hard drive?

Comment: @Nick Weinberg: I always create my partitions manually because the Ubuntu installer gets it wrong every time (on dual-boot and triple-boot). And GParted is faster at creating partitions.

Comment: @Jose Puebla: What problem? I once installed a ChromeOS on a 16GB sd card and it had 10 partitions on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an erase everything option while you boot from Ubuntu DVD. But I guess that will give you Ubuntu in a single partition. You can use a Gparted CD to make further partitions.